# Need help on unsupported characters

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, ascii

I am having a problem on what I think is a MySQL issue, when I trying fetch a row my the database(mysql) with a column value of ( à¤¹à¤¿à¤‚à¤¦à¥€ í•œêµ­ì–´ Ø§Ù„Ù„ØºØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ ), the result row seems exists and truthy on if condition statements. But when I var_dump it, it show empty, not null.

for example: (php/mysql)

Input Data:

- id -> 1
- name -> Bob
- address -> हिंदी 한국어 اللغة العربية

Stored Data on Table

- [column]id = 1
- [column]name = "Bob"
- [column]address = "à¤¹à¤¿à¤‚à¤¦à¥€ í•œêµ­ì–´ Ø§Ù„Ù„ØºØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ"

Expected Data after being fetched from mysql

- id -> "1"
- name -> "Bob"
- address -> \u00e0\u00a4\u00b9\u00e0\u00a4\u00bf\u00e0\u00a4\u201a\u00e0\u00a4\u00a6\u00e0\u00a5\u20ac \u00ed\u2022\u0153\u00ea\u00b5\u00ad\u00ec\u2013\u00b4 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00ba\u00d8\u00a9 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00b9\u00d8\u00b1\u00d8\u00a8\u00d9\u0160\u00d8

```
$mysql_result_row = array(
    "id" => 1, 
    "name" => "Bob",
    "address" => );

echo json_encode($mysql_result_row) // (shows nothing)
echo gettype($mysql_result_row) // array
echo $mysql_result_row['name'] // Bob
echo $mysql_result_row['address'] // (everything stops working, no php nor mysql error logs)
```

Notes

1. The sample above have 3 different set of language / character set.
2. à¤¹à¤¿à¤‚à¤¦à¥€ is Hindi
3. í•œêµ­ì–´ is Korean
4. Ø§Ù„Ù„ØºØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ is Arabic
5. Don't ask why a single column has 3 different language because I do not know
6. If only one of those languages on that address column, it works, no problem. It only stops working if those 3 combined

Comment: It seems to work here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1a3f58958240af1e1f017a3470a83514bd7347b

Comment: @Ray Romero welcome to SO, what is the collation you are using in the database for the particular field type

Comment: @DroidDev used to be utf8_general_ci then I convert it to utf8_unicode_ci, still the same.

Comment: @JayBlanchard the $mysql_result_row should come from mysql query using `select ...`

Comment: It does, doesn't it? You performed a select and an array was returned.

Comment: what is the mysql version you are using?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, my sample maybe confusing, but in my understanding assuming the database column has a value of  stated above, the result value from query would be like this ( \u00e0\u00a4\u00b9\u00e0\u00a4\u00bf\u00e0\u00a4\u201a\u00e0\u00a4\u00a6\u00e0\u00a5\u20ac \u00ed\u2022\u0153\u00ea\u00b5\u00ad\u00ec\u2013\u00b4 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00ba\u00d8\u00a9 \u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u201e\u00d8\u00b9\u00d8\u00b1\u00d8\u00a8\u00d9\u0160\u00d8 ). But since that issue I am experiencing I am unable to verify that

Comment: @DroidDev Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

Comment: In the example I provided the data is returned as described, so I am under where your issue it.

Comment: @RayRomero could you please post the insert data here?

Comment: It's Mojibake for `हिंदी 한국어 اللغة العربي' , with the Korean coming first.  See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  We'll need to see the HEX to determine whether it  might be "double encoding" instead.

Comment: @DroidDev updated the original post to include the input data, stored data on the mysql db, which I believe is the correct values. The issue is when fetching the data from the database, the php variable that is holding row becomes shady, then echoing/assigning the values of id and name has no issue, but echoing/assigning the value of address, then php server breaks with no error logs. Is it likely a mysql version or/and configuration? that the mysql is not encoding properly if multiple language on a single column/string?

Comment: @RayRomero Please ckeck the collation as `utf8_general_ci` for the column you are storing the language data. Also add the `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">` in `<head>` of your html. Finally add **charset=utf8** in your PDO connection as `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=test;charset=utf8", $username, $password);`. Hope you will get resolved by this : )

Comment: @DroidDev Already tried them except the <meta http... because the error happen before getting to html. Anyway thank you for trying, looks like this issue gonna get shelve and re-evaluated.

Comment: @RayRomero did you add charset=utf8 in db connection?

Comment: yes, already did that, and it is utf8 by default. i also tried changing the table collation on different types

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a work around from this reference: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html][1]

Solutions:

- Prepend an N on values involving the non-english values. Example on MySQL INSERT/UPDATE: "INSERT INTO ... () VALUES('$id', '$name', N'$address')"
- Before querying the INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT query, I first query this: "SET CHARACTER SET utf8"

Although the problem on the '$mysql_result_row' as stated on the question is still a mystery, it is still like partially corrupted variable because it is holding a character it cannot handle properly.